# Visual Studio 2019: EditorConfig does not work for some projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

We are using an .editorconfig which is located in the root of our repo. That is working fine except for some projects in one of our solutions. This is very strange.

For those projects it seems that all the settings which starts with `dotnet_` and `csharp_` are ignored.
Other settings like `indent_size` and `indent_style` are working fine.

It is about normal C# projects. I checked already the project file but cannot find any cause.

Visual Studio 2019 is used.

Does somebody know what can be the cause?